# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

this issue generally comes by below command of react.
react-scripts build && rm build/static/**/*.map and issue is  like

Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! `react-scripts build && rm build/static/**/*.map`

Comment: There should some issue in your code. Like you are trying to apply toLowerCase for a number value or the value is itself undefined. You can share codesandbox or jsfiddle. It would be more clear then.

Answer (score 0):

if any body facing this issue please check any reference giving undefined and we are calling the java script tolowercase method by this reference.but it wasn't my issue.
the issue was with CSS file. Please validate your CSS once by http://beautifytools.com/css-validator.php
and check any attribute is blank or not that might give you above exception.
Example:***.padding-left-min{padding-left:;}***